# Why can't I add this instance of a generic type to a collection?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

I have two abstract types with a many to many relationship:

```
public abstract class Experiment<T> where T : Sample
{
    private List<T> _Samples = new List<T>;
    public IReadOnlyCollection<T> Samples {
        get { return _Samples.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    public void AddSample(T sample)
    {
        _Samples.Add(sample); 
        sample.Experiments.Add(this); // The problem lies here
    }
}

public abstract class Sample
{
    private List<Experiment<Sample>> _Experiments = new List<Experiment<Sample>>;
    public ICollection<Experiment<Sample>> Experiments {
        get { return _Experiments; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, an experiment accepts a type parameter that is a subclass of `Sample`. What I am trying to do is this: whenever an instance of a subtype of `Sample` is added to an `Experiment`, the `Experiment` should correspondingly be added to the `Experiments` collection of the `Sample`.

The problem arises when I try to add an instance of an `Experiment<T>` to a collection that is `List<Experiment<Sample>>`. Since `T` is a subtype of `Sample`, I was assuming there wouldn't be a problem. What actually happens is the following:

```
Value of type 'Experiment<T>' cannot be converted to 'Experiment<Sample>`
```

My question is whether there is a way to work around this problem, or to better model the relationship between these entities.

Comment: PS: I actually work with VB, but there seems to be a larger C# audience on SO, which is why I've translated my code to C#. I believe the language shouldn't really make a difference to the approach used for solving the problem, but feel free to correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: Could you share the working VB code?

Comment: @CédricBignon There isn't actually "working" VB code per se, I get a compiler error at the line corresponding to the one commented above (i.e. `sample.Experiments.Add(Me)`). Did I goof up on the syntax up there?

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich A sample can undergo many experiments of differring types (consecutively), each of which adds some data to it. An experiment must run on one or more samples.

Comment: I see an error in your code. It looks like `Sample.Experiments` should be of type `ICollection<Experiment<Sample>>`. (But this does not answer to your question.)

Comment: @MichaelGunter Yes, that is correct, sorry. Fixed it.

Comment: You declare _Experiments but you it does not look like you new it.

Comment: @Blam That happens in the constructor, which I haven't actually included in this code. I'll edit the example to instantiate the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think the fix is this:

```
public abstract class Experiment<T> where T : Sample<T>
{
    private List<T> _Samples;
    public IReadOnlyCollection<T> Samples {
        get { return _Samples.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    public void AddSample(T sample)
    {
        _Samples.Add(sample); 
        sample.Experiments.Add(this); // The problem lies here
    }
}

public abstract class Sample<T> where T : Sample<T>
{
    private List<Experiment<T>> _Experiments;
    public ICollection<Experiment<T>> Experiments {
        get { return _Experiments; }
    }
}
```

Because the two types are dependent on each other then they need to share the same generic type.

Comment: `where T : Sample` What is the `Sample`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, it's a derived concrete class of `Sample`. If I were to build `ConcreteSample : Sample` it would satisfy that condition. Further, the OP wouldn't ever be passing in an instance of `Sample` because it's abstract.

Comment: It needs to be `public abstract class Sample<T> where T : Sample<T>`. It won't compile otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelGunter, fantastic observation. I'll edit, and thanks!

Comment: I see. So assuming I have something like `ThicknessSample` which reifies `Sample`, I would have it derive from `Sample<ThicknessSample>`?

Comment: @Asad, that's correct. It's an interesting recursion of generics really.

Comment: @Asa: Yes. This syntax looks strange, but it's not uncommon when dealing with generics.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud How do you create an instance of `Sample<Sample<Sample<Sample<...>>>>` ??

Comment: @CédricBignon, you wouldn't. When you inherited from `Sample` it would require a type (e.g. `public class MySample : Sample<MySample>`).

Comment: @CédricBignon I wouldn't have to, since `Sample` is never meant to be instantiated.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud That's a really interesting construction.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Please give me a moment to try and implement this in VB, and I'll come back and accept the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Asad, I look forward to hearing how it went!

Comment: It'll take while to get used the rather odd inheritance signature for descendants of `Sample`, but this did end up working out beautifully. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Experiment<T> where T : Sample
{
    private List<T> _Samples = new List<T>();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<T> Samples
    {
        get { return _Samples.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    public Experiment()
    {
    }

    public Experiment(IEnumerable<T> samples)
    {
        _Samples = samples.ToList();
    }

    public void AddSample(T sample)
    {
        _Samples.Add(sample);
        sample.Experiments.Add(new Experiment<Sample>(_Samples)); // The problem lies here
    }
}

public abstract class Sample
{
    private List<Experiment<Sample>> _Experiments = new List<Experiment<Sample>>();
    public ICollection<Experiment<Sample>> Experiments
    {
        get { return _Experiments ; }
    }
}
```

By adding some constructors and modifying the `Experiments` collection in `Sample` I think I was able to achieve what you're looking for. Now you can use the following code

```
public class MySample : Sample{}

public class MyExperiment : Experiment<MySample>{}

MyExperiment me = new MyExperiment();
me.AddSample(new MySample());
```

Comment: This would work, but unfortunately I failed to mention that an instance of an experiment is bound to lots of other data and instances of controller classes for hardware. Simply recreating an Experiment instance would be expensive, at the very least, and would require a lot more code to successfully move over data.